# Should I use a classification algorithm from sklearn or just euclidean distance

Tags: python, scikit-learn, statistics

I have N persons let's call them `p1`, `p2` and `p3`.

And I have K questions let's note them `Q1`, `Q2`, `Q3`, `Q4`.

Plus I have a variable called `data` which is a python3 dict:

```
data = {"p1": {"Q1":1, "Q2":0, "Q3":1, "Q4":0},
        "p2": {"Q1":1, "Q2":1, "Q3":1, "Q4":0},
        "p3": {"Q1":0, "Q2":0, "Q3":1, "Q4":1} }
```

This dictionary means that `p1` knows the answer to question 1 and 3 but not the answers to questions 2 and 4.

The problem is that we have an unknown person `pX`. We asked him our K questions and say we got:

```
"pX": {"Q1":1, "Q2":0, "Q3":1, "Q4":1}
```

The question to rank the N persons from the most likely to be `pX` to the least likely.

What I did was to simply compute the euclidean distance between each person and `pX`.

So I have

```
d1 = compute_distance(pX, p1)
d2 = compute_distance(pX, p2)
d3 = compute_distance(pX, p3)
```

Then I just sort the distances and thus I get the person most likely to be `pX` (having the smallest distance) to the least likely to be `pX` (having the higher distance).

And to finish I just present to the user each person with their distances sorted.

I find this approach easy to program and to do. However a friend told me that for N and K big, a classification algorithm would be better (using sklearn).

Is that true ? What would a classification algorithm (like KNN or forestTree) bring to the table  that the euclidean distance doesn't ?

Side question: Do you think there is another result that is interesting to see and to present to the user ? Like can we define an accuracy (the standard deviation of our data for example ?) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's re-phrase the question slightly. Instead of modeling the questions for each student as a series of Python dictionaries, we can define a 2D array of size `N` people times `K` questions. We can also define a "new" array of shape `K`.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import euclidean

X = np.array(
    [
        [1, 0, 1, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 1],
    ]
)

new_x = np.array([1, 0, 1, 1])
```

If the goal is to find the "most similar" vector in `X`, we can frame that as minimizing the distance between `X` and `new_x`. If we have no prior knowledge of the structure of `X`, the naive approach is to iterate over all elements of `X`, compare the euclidean distance, and return a tuple of `(distance, index)`:

```py
def most_similar_brute_force(X, new_x):
    # Return index in X with minimum Euclidean distance to new_x
    ind = -1
    minimum_distance = np.inf
    for i, u in enumerate(X):
        if euc := euclidean(u, new_x) < minimum_distance:
            minimum_distance = euc
            ind = i
    return euclidean(X[ind], new_x), ind


print(most_similar_brute_force(X, new_x))
# (1.0, 0)
```

But this is inefficient. Even assuming that euclidean distance can be calculated in `O(1)` time (by assuming that all math operations are constant), there's still a `O(N)` linear hurdle when we have to check every value.

A more efficient approach would involve building a `KDTree` data structure (see [scipy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html), or [Wikipedia's section on time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree#Complexity)). Assuming the tree is well-balanced, querying for the 1-nearest neighbor is `O(log N)` on average and can give the same result as our naive solution:

```py
from scipy.spatial import KDTree

tree = KDTree(X)

print(tree.query(new_x, k=1, p=2))
# (1.0, 0)
```

There's one caveat: in high-dimensional space, everything tends to be similar. The scipy `KDTree` documentation notes that performance may not be significant over the brute force approach for high-dimensions (roughly defined as K=20+).

Our `most_similar_brute_force` will probably be slower than `KDTree` since it's implemented in Python, but hints that a different approach may be needed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Indeed I did not think about performance. So, you agree with me that using classification (ie sklearn with training and fit) does not contribute to solve the problem ... I mean the best we can get from sklearn are the kdtree like you said ,,,

Comment: Sort of. I would not call this a classification problem since there do not appear to be any labels (recall that fitting a classification model in `scikit-learn` usually follows the pattern `.fit(X, y)` where we have a set of data `X` and labels `y`). You could frame this as a *clustering* problem if you want to group users into categories. Or if you had some knowledge that two examples `X_1` and `X_2` were similar, you could frame this as a [metric learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Similarity_learning) problem. Both would need more information.